# How to compile ClamAV library properly statically?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, static-linking, clam

I've compiled `clamav-0.99.2` as follows:
`~./configure -enable-static` and then `make & sudo make install`. Compilation was succeed as it seemed to me. But when added to my project **libclamav.a** in **`Qt5.8-static`**, it gives errors in compilation:

`:-1: error: /usr/local/lib/libclamav.a(libclamav_la-regex_pcre.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pcre_study' 
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3:-1: error: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line 
:-1: error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

In my `*.pro` static clamav library added as follows:

`LIBS +=/usr/local/lib/libclamav.a
 CONFIG += static
 CONFIG += staticlib`
Can you help me to compile clamav statically in my qt project?

Comment: Have you succeeded into compiling this library ? Because I am struggling right now to do this and I am searching for a little support ..

Comment: @flaviu2 Just use configuration as follows: `$ ./configure --enable-static`

Comment: I am compilling clamav library on VS2010, I am not using Qt ... did you compiled clamav as static ?

Comment: @flaviu2 Yeap! You do compile clamav without Qt, the above command uses `clamav` package configurations ... thats it.

Comment: I've just tried to bind clamav library to Qt, but couldn't.

Comment: Is it possible to statically build libclamunrar along with libclam? Anyone tried?

Comment: @IrfanLatif Personally, have NOT tried yet!